# Scala Quill: how to write? I need use GROUP BY and ORDER BY and multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: scala

I want to get sql like this:

```
SELECT
    v0.`uid`,
    v0.`title`,
    v0.`price`,
    v0.`publishtime`,
    v0.`status`,
    v0.`type`,
    v0.`is_lfst`,
    v0.`app_image`
FROM
    `news` v0
    LEFT JOIN `news_zq` v1 ON v0.`id` = v1.`nid` 
WHERE
    v0.`status` = 1 
    AND v0.`is_lfst` = 1 
    AND v0.`type` = 2
    AND v1.`zq_id` = 2
GROUP BY 
    v0.`id`  
ORDER BY
    v0.`publishtime` DESC
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I tried "dynamicQuery" and "infix",but failed

```
dynamicQuery[News]
        .leftJoin(dynamicQuery[NewsZq]).on((a, b) => a.id == b.nid)
        .filter(_._1.status == lift(1))
        .filterIf(newsDo.cid.isDefined && newsDo.cid.get > 0)(_._1.cid == lift(newsDo.cid.get))
        .filterIf(newsDo.`type`.isDefined)(_._1.`type` == lift(newsDo.`type`.get))
        .groupBy(_._1.id).map(_._2.map(_._1)) // error

        .sortBy(_._1.publishtime)(Ord.desc)
        .drop(quote(lift(offset)))
        .take(quote(lift(limit)))
        .map(_._1)
```

Comment: Why are you left joining when you are not reading anything from v1 and also groupping without aggregating.

Comment: updated! I have a where condition in v1